# How to get the list of running DAGs of composer airflow in a python script stored in DAG folder?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, airflow, airflow-scheduler, google-cloud-composer

All,

We have several number of JSON files with DAG information. I have created a python script to read those JSON files to generate the DAG's dynamically for Composer airflow. Now the challenge for me to get the list of running DAGs in my python script and triggering the single DAG from my local system.

In my local I have setup private SSH keys so I am able to get the list of DAGs running in composer airflow using below command.

```
gcloud -q composer environments run "$ENVIRONMENT" --location "$REGION" list_dags
```

I can use POST/GET request by using airflow server URL but facing authentication errors when I trigger it.

```
curl -X POST http://<airflow servername>api/experimental/dags/airflow_monitoring/dag_runs -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'Content-Length: 0'
```

Can someone please help me with below questions?

1. how to get the list of running DAGs in python script which is there in DAG folder of composer airflow?
2. I am not able to override "webserver-authenticate" airflow config variable using composer environment variables as this variable is blocked. How I can enable authentication if I am not able to override the config variable?
3. Is there a way to start the DAG by supplying generic credentials/individual credentials or some other way from anyones local system? I think I can complete this task by using Jenkins job but I wonder if it is doable from terminal/commandline.

Appreciate your help

Best Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Composer is a managed service from Google, and according to the [Architecture](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/concepts/overview#architecture), the Airflow Web Server is isolated in a tenant project. To be able to access you have to handle the authentication via the Identity-Aware Proxy. This can be a little bit difficult to achieve since you don't have access to the setup of the tenant project. You can use the Owner account to authenticate from the Web Browser to access the Airflow Web Server and use the Airflow API.

But if you want to try to do this inside of a script, you'll have to create a [JWT token](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/authentication-howto#authenticating_a_user_account). But there are issues around this option, since you don't have access to the tenant project and you need to properly setup the IAP and your script to be able to create the token.

A more reliable option to reach the server is to setup your own [Web Server](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/managing/deploy-webserver)

Also if what you want is to get the running DAGs you can also try with the [logs](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/concepts/logs). This way you may get a workaround.

As for the execution of a DAG, you can review how to trigger DAGs [here](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/using/triggering-with-gcf).